# Check if the item in recycler view selected

Tags: android, android-espresso

I would like to check the property of one of the items in `RecyclerView`. To be more specific I want to check if this item is selected.

Firstly I select the item

```
onView(withId(R.id.list_master))
            .perform(
                    RecyclerViewActions.actionOnItemAtPosition(14, clickAnItem(R.id.layout_menu))
            );
```

Secondly check if the specific item is selected:

```
        onView(allOf(withId(R.id.layout_menu), hasDescendant(withText("SO"))))
            .check(matches(isSelected()));
```

With custom matcher:

```
    private static Matcher<View> isSelected() {
    return new TypeSafeMatcher<View>() {
        @Override
        protected boolean matchesSafely(View item) {

            return item.isSelected();
        }

        @Override
        public void describeTo(Description description) {
            description.appendText("Selected property");
        }
    };
```

Sadly the state of this view is not selected, but UI shows it successfully marked as selected item. Implementation details

```
@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(RecyclerView.ViewHolder holder, int position) {
    final ViewHolder viewHolder = (ViewHolder) holder;
    viewHolder.itemView.setSelected(position == selected);
```

Answer (score 1):

Check this code I had the same thing want you want check whether the field is selected or not in Recycler View.

```
public class AutoWithRuleListListAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<AutoWithRuleListListAdapter.ViewHolder> {

private Context context;
private Fragment fragment;
private ArrayList<ObjGetLookupDataResponseIn> lookupData;


public AutoWithRuleListListAdapter(Context context, Fragment fragment, ArrayList<ObjGetLookupDataResponseIn> lookupData) {
    this.context = context;
    this.fragment = fragment;
    this.lookupData = lookupData;

}

@Override
public ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
    View view = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.auto_withdraw_ben_name_list, parent, false);
    return new ViewHolder(view);
}

@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(final ViewHolder holder, @SuppressLint("RecyclerView") final int position) {
    String output = lookupData.get(position).getDisplayName().substring(0, 1).toUpperCase() + lookupData.get(position).getDisplayName().substring(1);
    holder.radioBen.setText(output);
    holder.radioBen.setOnCheckedChangeListener(null);
    holder.radioBen.setChecked(lookupData.get(position).isSelected());

    holder.radioBen.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener() {
        @Override
        public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView, boolean isChecked) {
            resetAll();
            lookupData.get(position).setSelected(true);
            notifyDataSetChanged();
            ((AutoViewRuleFragment)fragment).ruleName(position);
        }
    });


}

private void resetAll() {
    for (int i=0;i<lookupData.size();i++)
    {
        lookupData.get(i).setSelected(false);
    }
    notifyDataSetChanged();
}


@Override
public int getItemCount() {
    return lookupData.size();
}

public class ViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
    RadioButton radioBen;

    public ViewHolder(View itemView) {
        super(itemView);

        radioBen = (RadioButton) itemView.findViewById(R.id.radioReceivesFunds);
        radioBen.setTypeface(Utils.gothamMedium);

    }
}}
```

rulename method in my fragment through which i get the position of the view.Add boolean selected in your POJO if this item is selected or not.
Hope this help.Happy Coding.Vote if you find it useful.

Comment: Thank you, but my question relates to the espresso test. Unfortunately this answer is irrelevant